# when and why does programmers use octal and hexadecimal literals in java?

Tags: java, hex, literals, octal

As a beginner, I am learning java, and I learned about literals. I got to know that octal and hex literals contain 3 and 4 bits. We can use them instead of binary literals to write more readable code. We can use _ (underscores) in binary or big integer literals to make them readable.

Then why do we actually use hex or octal?

Comment: The only place I have ever practically used octal is for specifying Unix file permissions (e.g. `0644`), where it makes sense to use octal because each of the operations has three bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *hex* because it's shorter than *binary* when doing **bit-manipulation**. No idea why anyone would use *octal*.

E.g. when extracting the Green value from an RGB `int`, you would use `(rgb >> 8) & 0xFF` because `0xFF` is much better than `255`, `0377`, and `0b11111111` in this context.

Comment: You'd use octal in [18-bit computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/18-bit_computing), obvs.

Comment: @AndyTurner And what *ancient* 18-bit computing system runs Java?

Comment: as I commented above, I have only ever used octal for Unix file permissions. I think it's useful to know historical context for why things exist, even if they are not directly useful. As to why they *need to* exist in Java: other than file permissions, it was likely just another thing to make C programmers feel at home.

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out the fact that more recent languages than Java also support octal. It's the weird uncle you have to invite to the party, even if nobody really knows why it's there any more.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh, I agree that's it's a weird uncle inherited from C, and in all my many year, I've never used octal. But you comment that *nix file permissions use them is a valid observation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider dealing with 32-bit data

```
int x = 0b1111_1111_0000_0000_1111_1111_0000_0000;
```

using hexadecimal

```
int x = 0xFF00FF00;
```

More readable and easier to type. Octals are pretty rare in the wild but the same applies.